# Why isn't my variance calculation right?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, variance

Let $K$ be a random variable with mean $\mathbf E[K]=e$, and $\textrm{var}(K)=v$.  Let $X_1,X_2\ldots$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables, all independent of $K$, with mean $1$ and variance $1$.  Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$.  Calculate $\textrm{var}(X)$.

---

My calculation:

$\mathbf E[X]=\mathbf E[X_1+\ldots +X_K]$

$=\mathbf E\Bigl[\mathbf E\bigl[(X_1+\ldots +X_K)\mid K\bigr]\Bigr]$

$=\mathbf E\bigl[K\mathbf E[X_1]\bigr]$

$=\mathbf E[K\cdot 1]$

$=e$

$\mathbf E[X^2]=\mathbf E\bigl[(X_1+\ldots +X_K)(X_1+\ldots +X_K)\bigr]$

$=\mathbf E\Bigl[\mathbf E\bigl[(X_1+\ldots +X_K)(X_1+\ldots +X_K)\mid K\bigr]\Bigr]$

$=\mathbf E\Bigl[\mathbf E\bigl[(X_1+\ldots +X_K)\mid K\bigr]\mathbf E\bigl[(X_1+\ldots +X_K)\mid K\bigr]\Bigr]$

$=\mathbf E\bigl[K\mathbf E[X_1]K\mathbf E[X_1]\bigr]$

$=\mathbf E[K^2]$

$=\textrm{var}(K) + \bigl(\mathbf E[K]\bigr)^2$

$=v+e^2$

$\textrm{var}(X)=\mathbf E[X^2]-\bigl(\mathbf E[X]\bigr)^2=v+e^2-e^2=v$

---

Given solution:

$\textrm{var}(X)=\textrm{var}(X_i)\mathbf E[K]+\bigl(\mathbf E[X_i]\bigr)^2\textrm{var}(K)=e+v$

---

Can someone point out what I did wrong?  I don't quite follow the given solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your computation of the second moment, you did

$$E\left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^KX_i\sum_{j=1}^KX_j|K\right)\right]=E\left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^KX_i|K\right)\right]E\left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^KX_i|K\right)\right]$$

This step is not correct.

Also, I believe it's a typo, in the computation of $E[X]$, the final solution is $e$ and not $v$.

Edit:

We use the [Law of total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance),

\begin{align}Var(X)&=E[Var(X|K)]+Var(E(X|K)) \\
&=E\left[Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^K X_i|K\right)\right]+ Var(KE(X_1))\\
&= E[KVar(X_1)]+(E(X_1))^2Var(K)\\
&= Var(X_1)E[K] + (E(X_1))^2Var(K)\end{align}

Comment: Type fixed.  How do you achieve the first equality of the given solution?

Comment: I see the error in the step you point out.  $X$ is not independent of itself so I cannot take that out of the bracket.

Comment: they use the law of total variance.

Comment: GAAAAHH!!!  How did I forget????  Thank you!!!!!!